# MYSQL DB structure - Car makers / models / parts cascading dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cascadingdropdown

I'm building an app where user is asked to first select car maker, than model, than part, and than part no. The values for dynamic dropdown will be loaded via Ajax.

What is the best way to store the values in mysql db? Should I have separate table for each dropdown? Like

**Table car_makers**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | car maker |
+----+-----------+
```

**Table car_models**

```
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | car_maker_id | car model |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

**Table car_parts**

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | car_model_id | car_part |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

Or should I just make one super-large table?

Comment: you have tagged your question very badly. You ask a broad Database performance question and dont event tell us what database you use.

Comment: I think this is general db structure question - anyway, I added mysql to the description.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to query if there are 3 tables, you can also declare foreign keys so that the schema ensures a part is linked to a model.

You might also need to have the same part shared by two or more models, then you need a link table between models and parts.